# Relative layout wrap width and height according to background image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

The problem which i am facing is very strange relative layout is not warping width and height according to image.it is showing relativelayout on full screen as you can see [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emSYD.png)
Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/img_bg_wood">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/nine_man_morris" >
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I solve the issue when i place ImageView in relative layout it works perfect as you can see [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzt83.png).

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/img_bg_wood">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/nine_man_morris" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**But the problem is i don't want to use imageview** because it is still shows RelativeLayout in full screen. i want to wrap relativelayout according to image just like the above code showing.

Comment: background is not content, so ```wrap_content``` property could not determine actual size of content, you need to use ```ImageView```, but you can avoid unnecessary ```RelativeLayout``` which wrap ```ImageView```

Comment: i place the inner relativelayout because you can see stars on background image where i will place the buttons that's way i take the inner relativelayout.basically it is a game [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Men%27s_Morris).

Comment: i think background is content if it is not why it works for ImageView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/img_bg_wood">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/nine_man_morris"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't have the word the thank you.
it works great thats the solution i am looking for thank u soooooooooo much..

Comment: It works great if a remove this line from RelativeLayout
android:background="@drawable/nine_man_morris"
and change this line of ImageView
android:src="@drawable/nine_man_morris"

Comment: @HareshChhelana  how can i set relativelayout height and width of image to my imageview ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#A0000000"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >


        <!-- The Background Image -->           
        <ImageView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:id="@+id/background_image"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_pic"


                />



        <!-- The view group containd around the image -->
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/background_image"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/background_image"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/background_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">








            </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

This should solve your problem